# PopUp window should not open with copy paste URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am opening popup window after login process,

Now the requirement that on can't open that particular pop window by copy pasting url in the browser

I  have use this code but it is not working.

```
    Dim urlcopy As String = ""
    If Request.UrlReferrer IsNot Nothing Then
        urlcopy = Request.UrlReferrer.Segments(Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Length - 1)
    End If
    If urlcopy = "" Then
        Response.Redirect("~/GenError.aspx") -- reaching here at normal case also
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

A referrer or an URL to a page has nothing to do with security. If you don't want the user to access a certain page when not logged in, then check whether the user is logged in when that page is requested.

If it's only about the popup part: to my knowledge you can't detect whether a page is displayed in a popup or a 'regular' browser window.